# Biquad high-pass filter - calculating filter slope

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, dsp-core, biquad

I have to design high-pass IIR Biquad filter with cutoff frequency of 80Hz, sampling frequency 24kHz, and filter slope of 24dB/oct @ 80Hz. I have used formula for HPF biquad coefficients from [here](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt). However, the slope is less steep for frequencies lower than 80Hz, please see the picture. How I can design a filter to give me 24dB/oct for the frequencies lower than 80Hz, to match the reference curve on the picture?

[image]

Comment: You might find that one biquad is not enough for the slope you want. Try cascading two of them in series and you will often get a steeper slope.

Comment: Try a 4th order Butterworth. 2nd order (biquad) is not enough. We've talked about order and dB/octave when discussing [your other question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23320/fir-filter-design-input-parameters-conversion), haven't we?

Comment: Anthony Parks, thank you, that worked. Matt, yes we did discuss, I learned a lot. I used frequency sampling method to obtain custom slope for FIR filters. Anthony, you can write your comment as the answer for my question.